# How to use Storyboard after selecting SwiftUI during project creation?

Tags: swift, storyboard, swiftui

I created a project to try out SwiftUI and have been working on the same for a few days. I don't feel very comfortable with SwiftUI as of now and wish to use Storyboard instead in the project.
Trying out for some time but it is always giving me black screen on application launch.

Added Main Storyboard and set the same in settings.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

We need to manually set the Storyboard name in Project Info Scene Configuration.